# How can I overwrite multiple lines with echo or printf in shell?

Tags: string, shell, replace, printf, overwrite

I have some shell functions, one draws some ASCII art to the screen on multiple lines eg:

```
printf %s '
______________
||__________||

'
sleep 1
clear
printf %s '
______________
||__________||
      ||
      ||
      ||

'
sleep 1
clear
printf %s '
______________
||__________||
      ||
      ||
      ||
||‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾||
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
'
```

is there a way to overwrite the string without clearing the screen? I have tried using \r on every line and on the last line but that only seems to replace one line strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends completely on your terminal. Many terminals allow to send an escape sequence *move cursor to home position*. This might be available as the terminfo(1) command

```
tput home
printf 'Cursor now home\n'
```

See `man terminfo` if you have it. If not, you need to tell us the value of your `TERM` environment variable (`echo $TERM`).